# Creating InputImageData from Uint8List or Image Object For Google ML Kit Face Detection

Tags: flutter, google-mlkit

Ho do we create an `InputImage` if all we have is `Uint8List` or `Image` object? How do we create the Plane object needed to initialize the `InputImageData`?

```
//imageFile is an XFile dataType (From Camera Package) 

Uint8List imageData = await imageFile.readAsBytes();
```

The link below from the Google ML Kit GitHub page doesn't describe how we can create an Input Image if we only have Uint8List object.

[CREATING INPUT IMAGE](https://github.com/bharat-biradar/Google-Ml-Kit-plugin/tree/master/packages/google_mlkit_commons#creating-an-inputimage)

Comment: https://pub.dev/documentation/google_mlkit_commons/latest/google_mlkit_commons/InputImage/InputImage.fromBytes.html

Comment: @pskink The problem is we need to create InputImageData which requires Plane object.

Comment: Where does the `UInt8List` come from? Is it from an API call? And what's the content of it (a PNG, JPG ...)?

Comment: @lepsch Uint8List imageData = await imageFile.readAsBytes(); //imageFile is an XFile dataType from the Camera Package

Comment: InputImage is not part of material.dart. Where is it? So that I can try it out...

Comment: @KarolinaHagegård InputImage is from Google ML Kit Face Detection Package https://pub.dev/packages/google_mlkit_face_detection/install

Comment: Put that in your qn instead! You should make it easy for ppl to help you. 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have named "imageData" in your code is not actually an ImageData. It's a list of bytes. You say that you got this list of bytes this way:

```
//imageFile is an XFile dataType (From Camera Package) 

Uint8List imageData = await imageFile.readAsBytes();
```

So clearly, you have an XFile that you have called "imageFile".

On this page, from your package:

https://github.com/bharat-biradar/Google-Ml-Kit-plugin/blob/master/packages/google_ml_kit/example/lib/vision_detector_views/camera_view.dart

you find, for example:

```
final path = pickedFile?.path;  // Where pickedFile is an XFile, like your imageFile
//...
final inputImage = InputImage.fromFilePath(path);
```

This should work with your imageFile! If it doesn't, please explain what happens.

PS On the same page, you can also see how to get `planeData` from a `CameraImage`... but that's not the same as an XFile, so. It may not be so relevant, to you.

Comment: I don't have the image file, so saving it and reading it back isnt very wise. We cannot put nothing into the InputImageData constructor because it will return an error

Comment: You don't have the image file??... But you said you had a Uint8List which you got from `Uint8List imageData = await imageFile.readAsBytes();`!... There's an `imageFile` in that expression!

Comment: In any case, for my `inputImage` above, you don't need the imageFile. You need only the Uint8List, which I have chosen to call `bytes`.

Comment: And btw, my code doesn't return error when I put nothing in the `InputImageData()` object!... But if yours does, what happens if you write: `InputImageData(size: Size(50, 50))`?

Comment: InputImageData(
      {required this.size,
      required this.imageRotation,
      required this.inputImageFormat,
      required this.planeData});

Comment: Which version of the google_ml_kit package are you using? I'm using `google_ml_kit: ^0.3.0` and I've added a full code to my answer above, which runs fine in my end, without any errors!

Comment: Ooooooh, I see it now! You're using a totally different package...!  See, this is why we take care to always specify which packages we're using in the qn! Now, I googled it and found my own package which I thought was the correct one. It had all the elements! Then when you answered, I didn't click the link, coz by then, I thought I already knew the answer!
   Ok, I might look at the right package tomorrow, but now, I'm tired from working with the wrong one for long. 
   In any case, my `InputImage2` above should work for you!

Comment: The Google ML Kit Face Detection package is a subset package. It requires the planeData parameter. Thanks for your answer

Comment: I've updated my answer to the correct package. Plz read, and clarify why if it doesn't work!

Comment: Thanks fo rthe help

Comment: Thanks for the reward!  I had to work hard for it...